# Does BlogEngine.Net have a custom HttpHandler for all .aspx requests?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, pagemethods, blogengine.net

I'm working on customizing BlogEngine.Net to be able to return some HTML from an AJAX call. Basically I'd like to render a UserControl server-side and then return the resulting HTML to a client-side call.

I've done this many times in other applications using static PageMethods marked with the [WebMethod] attribute. But any time I try this with BlogEngine.Net, I get the full HTML of the page returned. It doesn't even look like the WebMethod is getting touched.

I've also tried to implement this as an HttpHandler, but I have the same result. As soon as I include a page (vanilla Page class) and use it to render the control, I get the full HTML of the page I am calling from instead of the generated code, leading me to assuming something is hijacking my code to render a Page.

Any ideas or alternate solutions to be able to render a user control server-side and return the HTML using the BlogEngine.Net framework?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code of CommentView.ascx, they do the same thing using ICallbackEventHandler. That basically renders the comment preview and also the comment itself.

However, it should be possible to do it like you said too, with [WebMethod]. I have actually customized my own setup to change CommentView to use a [WebMethod] and it works fine.

For an example of their own [WebMethod] implementation, have a look at AjaxHelper under admin folder, it's a dummy page whose purpose is to serve these web methods.

The above are for BlogEngine.NET 2.6.